# Is it possible to test two way binding of scope.trains in the directive using jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test 2-way binding in a custom directive using jasmine.

This is js:

```
angular.module('MyServiceModule',[]);

angular.module('MyServiceModule').controller('MyController',MyController);
angular.module('MyServiceModule').directive('trainDirective',trainDirective);



function MyController($http)
{
    console.log('MyController');
    vm = this;

    vm.openCreateQuoteScreen = function(trainName)
    {
            alert("train type"+trainName);
    }

    vm.trainList = [
                         {"trainName":"Shatabdi"},
                         {"trainName":"Rajdhani"}
                   ];
}



function trainDirective()
{
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>TRAIN LIST</div>'+
                    '<ul data-ng-repeat="train in trains">'+
                    '<li>{{ train.trainName }}</li></ul>',

        scope: {
            trains: '=',

        },
    };
}
```

This is html:

```
<div ng-app="MyServiceModule" ng-controller="MyController as MyCtrl" >
     <train-directive trains="MyCtrl.trainList"> </train-directive>
</div>
```

How can I write the test 2-way data binding in below test:

```
describe('my directive', function(){
beforeEach(module('MyServiceModule'));

beforeEach(function(){  
        element=angular.element('<train-directive trains="MyCtrl.trainList"> </train-directive>');
         compiledElement = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    });
});
it('should test two-way data binding',function(){
    element.isolateScope().trains = "My trains";


      //Now I want to test if the same value is reflected in the parent scope's trainList variable.

expect(scope.trainList).toEqual('My trains');

    });
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Can anyone explain how can I correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

Bindings are not updated magically, they are updated on digests. `MyCtrl.trainList` should be changed to `trainList`, because `scope` doesn't belong to real controller with controllerAs syntax and doesn't have `MyCtrl` object.

It should be

```
   element.isolateScope().trains = "My trains";
   scope.$digest();
   ...
```

Comment: Is there any way I can test it with 'controllerAs' syntax ?

Comment: @A_J `controllerAs` functionality is tested by Google, you may take their word for it. This spec tests specifically `train-directive` binding and should be unaware of `MyController`. The good thing about directives with isolated scope is that they can be used and tested in isolation, it is unnecessary to recreate environmental conditions for them.